# Cистема отслеживания изменения данных MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

> cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes Недопустимое имя объекта

Люди добрые, подскажите, в чем проблема?

**Добавлено**

```
CREATE TABLE InventoryStudents
(ID intidentity(1,1) notnull primarykey,
 StudentsName varchar(200) notnull,
 StudyYear smallint null)
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema=N'dbo',
    @source_name=N'InventoryStudents',
    @role_name=N'cdc_Admin',
    @capture_instance=N'HR_InventoryStudents',
    @supports_net_changes=1,
    @filegroup_name=N'PRIMARY'
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10),@to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('HR_InventoryStudents')
SET @to_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT*FROM cd.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_HR_InventoryStudents
(@from_lsn,@to_lsn,N'all')
```

Answer (score 1):

> `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_экземпляр_отслеживания`,
> где **экземпляр_отслеживания**
> является значением, указывающим
> экземпляр отслеживания, если для
> исходной таблицы включена система
> отслеживания измененных данных.

[Источник](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510627.aspx).

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.